# zsh git completion offers different parameters then current prefix

Tags: git, zsh, zsh-completion

Typing in zsh

```
% git diff --ca<hit TAB>
```

offers

```
--cached  -1        -3        -C        -M        -R        -U        -l        -q        -w                        
-0        -2        -B        -G        -O        -S        -b        -p        -u        -z
```

so there are completions completely out of the current typed prefix. How can I fix it?

My completion configuration is:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

unsetopt AUTO_MENU MENU_COMPLETE COMPLETE_IN_WORD

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt %SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose false
```

Comment: I've been seeing this too on my config, but I don't know why either.